# Using a vector as a parameter (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print the even numbers of the first 25 Fibonacci numbers.  However, I think I have a problem when using a vector as a parameter for my function below.  Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int j=1, k=1, sum;
  vector<int> myvector(25);
  for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
    //cout << j << " ";
    myvector[i] = j;
    sum=j+k;
    j=k;
    k=sum;
}
    findeven(myvector);
    system("pause");
}



int findeven (vector<int>){
for (int i = 0, i < 25; i++){
if (vector[i] % 2 == 0){
    cout << vector[i];
}
}
else{
}
```

}

Comment: What problem do you think you have?

Comment: You need to name the parameter something... the function should be something like: `int findeven (vector<int> numbers)`

Comment: Interesting parameter there. Perhaps a *name* would help. Regarding what is ultimately wrong, code that *compiles* will likely fix this for you.

Comment: Pass the vector as a const reference if you don't modify it

Comment: The words vector in my findeven function are underlined red.

Answer (score 5):

`vector<int>` is just a type name. You need to name the parameter to be able to use it. You also can't use a type name as variable as you attempt to do in your loop. Fixed code:

```
int findeven( vector<int> v ) {
    if (v[i] % 2 == 0)
        cout << v[i];
    //...
}
```

Since you don't change the vector inside the function, it'd be a good idea to pass it by const reference to avoid copying it:

```
int findeven( const vector<int>& v );
```

You'll also need to make the function visible before you use it. Right now, it's defined after `main` function and you'll get an error because you're trying to call it where the compiler hasn't seen its declaration yet. Put it before `main` (or at least its declaration).

Comment: vector isn't modified past a const reference

Comment: So I can't loop through my vector to test if it is even or odd?

Comment: Okay thankyou.  Also, am I calling my function correctly?